# How do I move an ongoing comment swarm to chat when the OP has only 1 point?

Tags: support

I can't find an answer to this and have searched through the matches that I could find with no avail.

I have a user that needs my help but the comments have become a storm.  I would like to move this to chat until we get the problem resolved.. then post a solution back to the original post.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.  I have gotten the automated "move this to chat" message in the past but I don't want it to get to that.  When I look at existing posts, it says I can start a generic stack exchange chat but the user has to have at least N points (where my user has but 1).

Can anyone either help or simply tell me that I am SOL?

Answer (score 2):

You flag it for moderator attention, or use the "move to chat" button yourself.

Moving a conversation to chat *should*, if I remember rightly, grant explicit permission for any users with linked chat profiles to use the room as if they had earned the 20 reputation needed already.

Picking a chat room created this way at random: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/130143/discussion-on-answer-by-yorsubs-launch-a-windows-executable-from-run-menu-in-a-s?tab=access

There is an "access" tab where users have been granted "Explicit write access" which means that they should be able to use the room regardless of reputation. All you need the person to do is to "log in" to chat using the same profile they use for the main site.

Moderators have a dedicated "move to chat" button that can also optionally delete all the current comments along with creating the room.

If you need to add users to the room that were not originally in the comment thread then you should contact a moderator.

Comment: `move to chat` (it's not called that for us normals) does not always appear, I honestly, have never seen it except after way too many comments.

Comment: @Ramhound I did mean the link you get after a long comment chain. I'm not sure of the exact criteria of when it does actually appear though.

Comment: @Mokibai - In my experience the link appears between 10 and 20 comments. I have in 5 years never determined the requirements for it to appear